# slf4j/log4j log file not created

Tags: java, maven, log4j, slf4j

My maven project results in a WAR file deployed on Tomcat

I have included the dependency to slf4j-log4j like that in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```

The log4j.properties file looks like that (I've made sure that it is actually being deployed in the war file and ends up in WEB-INF/classes):

```
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, MyFile

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.MyFile=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.MyFile.File=${catalina.base}/logs/MyFile.log
log4j.appender.MyFile.ImmediateFlush=true

log4j.appender.MyFile.Threshold=DEBUG

log4j.appender.MyFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MyFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p [%t]: %m%n
```

The following code should afaik produce a log file in my tomcat logs folder named MyFile.log which also includes my log output ... but it doesn't. The file is not even being created.

EDIT2: Instead I found out that the log entries are being written to STDOUT instead of the log file of the FileAppender...

EDIT3: I tested on two different Tomcats (one on Suse Linux, the other on Windows as a service). The result is essentially the same

```
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

...

logger.info("User {} not found", cn);
```

EDIT:

- I checked that log4j's jar file is also being deployed
- User rights are sufficient to create the log file. In my very first test I even saw the file being created (but still empty). In subsequent tests the logfile has no longer been created

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you also deploy log4j.jar into the /lib folder?

Comment: slf4j-log4j has a dependency to log4j, so yes, log4j has also been deployed to WEB-INF/lib (I also checked)

Comment: Just wanted to make sure ... And user rights are also no problem? Can your App create files in catalina.base/logs?

Comment: The rights are sufficient. During my very first test I saw the MyFile.log being created (but it stayed empty). In subsequent tests the file is no longer being created

Comment: Maybe you should add this info to question. Those were my 2 cents. Haven't got much experience with tomcat, I'm afraid ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue using the following log4j.xml instead of log4j.properties. I'm not sure about the reason why though ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="MyFile" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="${catalina.base}/logs/MyFile.log"/>
        <param name="Append" value="true"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5p %c{1}:%M - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="info"/>
        <appender-ref ref="MyFile"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the file path to `log4j.appender.MyFile.File=logs/MyFile.log`. Since the the Tomcat installation dir is the current dir for your application, it must work without parameter `${catalina.base}` which might not exist in the context of your application.

Comment: Doesn't help. In the meantime I found out that the log entries are being written to STDOUT instead of the log file of the FileAppender...

Comment: Then also have a look at your stderr log file. Log4j usually writes there information on any problems with configuration.